# ¿Por que multiplicar los números de un arreglo me da undefined?

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito multiplicar todos los elementos de un `array` y por alguna extraña razón me da `undefined` hasta llegar al número 4. ¿Qué es lo que sucede?

Este es el código que utilizo:

```js
var numeros = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (var i = 0; i <= numeros.length - 1; i++) {
  console.log(numeros[i * i]);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas multiplicando los indices, no los valores.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```js
var numeros = [0, 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


for (var i = 0; i <= numeros.length - 1; i++) {
  console.log(numeros[i] * numeros[i]);

}
```

Comment: +1, esta es la respuesta más acertada

Answer (score 1):

Tu código no funciona porque estas multiplicando los índices, entonces mas allá el 11 no hay mas elementos. Yo utilizaría `map()` y [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/pow)  para hacer la potencia 2.

```js
var numeros = [0, 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];    
    
numeros = numeros.map(e=>Math.pow(e, 2));

console.log(numeros);
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema que tienes es que en lugar de multiplicar los valores por el índice, estas tratando de acceder a un elemento del array cuyo indice es el resultado de de multiplicarse a si mismo en cada iteración.

Solo llegas hasta el cuarto elemento que es 3, debido a que numeros[3*3] = numeros[9] = 9. Sin embargo, a partir del quinto elemento el resultado es el siguiente: numeros[5*5] = numeros[25] = undefined, ya que ese índice no existe dentro del array.

La manera correcta de realizar esa opereación en ES6 es usando map().

```js
let numeros = [0, 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    
numeros.map((numeroActual, indiceNumeroActual) => console.log(numeroActual * indiceNumeroActual));
```

Por qué no usar var?:
https://platzi.com/blog/como-funciona-el-scope-en-javascript/
Cómo funciona map()?:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Como ya han comentado, estas multiplicando los indices.
Yo atacaria la resolucion usando el metodo .map() de esta forma:

```js
let numeros = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

let numerosMultiplicados = numeros.map(numero=>numero*2)

console.log(numerosMultiplicados)
```

Espero te sirva el aporte. Saludos.